# Can I store HERE geocoding API results into a database?

Tags: here-api

I need clarification on the terms and conditions around database storage of the HERE geocoding API results.

What would be required is to store location (latitude, longitude, address) data in a database to recall later in a web app (vue js/dotnet api). This location could be anywhere in the world, and is not limited to just a single country.
An example would be a user needs to link content (images, text) to a corresponding geolocation. The data recalled would be displayed on a map, or list in the web app.

Google API has terms and conditions around storing and caching that basically don't allow what I'm looking to do. Mapbox allows geocoding storage for a higher price than their temporary geocoding, which I'm considering.

Thanks for responding!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for HERE (just FYI) and I found the answer here:

> Storing results from geocodes is not allowed for Location Services products in our Freemium and Pro plans. Please contact us for a plan that supports storing results from geocodes.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a __link or reference__ to a location where you "found the answer", in case of future updates to legal restrictions or terms & conditions.

Comment: Good point. I no longer work at HERE. I tried to find where I _thought_ this was spelled out, but failed to do so. Sorry!